# DB2/LUW SQL how to retrieve all table names for given schema, and filter for tables which contain specific field and value

Tags: sql, database, db2, db2-luw

I am trying to find all table names of a certain schema, this works with the following query:

```
--for DB2/LUW
select * from sysibm.systables
where CREATOR = 'SCHEMA'
and name like '%CUR%'
and type = 'T';
```

Now I want to filter these tables again, so that I only get those that contain a certain field with a certain value. I have tried to achieve this by using a cursor and looping through its rows.

```
begin
declare tableName varchar(255);
declare v_at_end integer default 0;
declare not_found CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '02000';
declare c1 cursor for
    select * from sysibm.systables where CREATOR = 'SCHEMA' and name like '%CUR%' and type = 'T';
declare CONTINUE HANDLER FOR not_found SET v_at_end;

open c1;

fetch_loop:
    loop
    fetch c1 into tableName;
    if v_at_end <>0 THEN
        leave fetch_loop;
    end if;
    --how can I print current tableName? following does not work, but also doesn't throw an error I am using AQT:
    call DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(tableName);

    --no kind of select works here, why? (SQL0104N SQLSTATE=42601)

    -- tested with:
    -- select * from SCHEMA.A_TABLE_NAME;

    -- I want to use current tableName, also doesn't work, some tries:
    -- select * from SCHEMA.:tableName where fieldName = 123456;
    -- select * from :tableName where fieldName = 123456;
    -- select name from sysibm.systables where CREATOR = 'SCHEMA' and name = :tableName and type = 'T';

end loop fetch_loop;
close c1;
end;
```

How to get all tables names of tables containing an entry with a specific field and value for the field? Would be cool to output all the names in a "console" or store them in a file.

Comment: The keyword to search for is "dynamic SQL".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON@

BEGIN
  DECLARE V_DUMMY INT;
  DECLARE V_STRING_TO_FIND VARCHAR (100) DEFAULT 'EMPLOYEE';

  FOR C1 AS
    SELECT
      C.TABSCHEMA 
    , C.TABNAME
    , 'SET ? = (SELECT 1 FROM "' 
    || C.TABSCHEMA || '"."' || C.TABNAME 
    || '" WHERE "' || C.COLNAME 
    || '" = ''' || V_STRING_TO_FIND || ''' FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)'
    AS CMD
    FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS C
    JOIN SYSCAT.TABLES T ON (T.TABSCHEMA, T.TABNAME) = (C.TABSCHEMA, C.TABNAME) AND T.TYPE = 'T'
    WHERE C.TABSCHEMA LIKE 'SYS%' AND C.COLNAME = 'TABNAME'
  DO
    --CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (C1.CMD);
    PREPARE S1 FROM C1.CMD;
    EXECUTE S1 INTO V_DUMMY;
    IF V_DUMMY IS NOT NULL THEN
      CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Found in: "' || C1.TABSCHEMA || '"."' || C1.TABNAME || '"');
    END IF;
  END FOR;

END@

SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF@
```